# como sumar numeros teniendo como limite el numero 30?

Tags: javascript, html

hola amigos tengo un problema , quiero sumar números con un limite , seria el numero 1 y el numero 30 , cuando le sumo un numero a otro, no debe sobrepasar ese numero limite , por ejemplo si sumo 20+12, em vez de 32 ,debería ser 2 , ósea que empiece del 1 otra vez, como podría hacerlo?

mi codigo en JavaScript:

```
var valor1 = variable1(ejemplo 20)
var valor2 = variable2(ejemplo 12)
 
var resultado= +valor1 + valor2
console.log(resultado erróneo= 32)
console.log(resultado deseado= 2)
```

Comment: Eso no es php ._.

Comment: jaja si recién veo que me equivoque

Comment: revisa lo nuevo que puse @RodrigoCamacho

Answer (score 1, accepted):

se me ocurre hacer una funcion recursiva, que la condicion de salida sea que sea igual o menor a 30:

```
if(resultado <= 30){
        return resultado;
      }
```

En otro caso le va quitando 30 en la siguiente vuelta, quedaria de la siguiente manera.

```js
var resultado= reloadSum(0,62)
console.log(resultado)

function reloadSum(valor1,valor2){
  resultado=+valor1+valor2
  if(resultado <= 30){
    return resultado;
  }
  return reloadSum(+valor1-30, valor2);
}
```

Comment: así me salió perfecto gracias =D

Comment: @RodrigoCamacho recuerda marcar como aceptada la respuesta que resolvió tu pregunta, así otros sabrán cómo resolver este mismo problema en el futuro.

Answer (score 1):

Para hacer eso debes usar el **operador de resto**, que se escribe con el **símbolo de %**.

Este es un **operador binario** ya que funciona con **dos operandos** ej.:

```
op1 % op2
```

Tu ejemplo se resuelve de esta forma:

```
var resultado = (valor1 + valor2) % 30;

if(resultado == 0)
{
   resultado = 30;
}
```

Se suman los dos valores y a esa suma se le aplica el mencionado **operador**, devolviéndote el resultado deseado.

En caso de que el **operador de resto** aplicado a la suma de los dos valores sea **0**, entonces a resultado le asignamos el valor **30**.

Comment: gracias es eso, pero lo probé así : var resultado = (20 + 10) % 30; console.log(resultado) y da de resultado 0 , si lo pongo así: var resultado = (20 + 10) % 31;console.log(resultado) muestra el 30, pero si sumo 20 + 11 da 0, mi idea es que muestre el 30 y si se pasa ,que el resultado sea 1 , se puede?

Comment: @RodrigoCamacho revisa lo nuevo q puse, solamente debes añadir una condicion if en tu codigo